# How to allocate more ram to minecraft?

Tags: java, games, ram, minecraft

Minecraft lags badly in my linux than windows! in windows i dont find trouble playing it!

My system specs : 
                   processor : AMD Athlon x2 260 3.2ghz dual core

```
              Graphic card : Ati radeon 3000 series
```

- ram : 4gb (3.25 usable)

I have ubuntu 12.04 and I want allocate more ram to minecraft!

I have 4gb physical ram (ONLY 3.25 USABLE)

I have openjdk 7

ALSO TELL ME OTHER WAYS TO RUN MINECRAFT SMOOTHLY!
PLEASE HELP!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

From what ive read, Ubuntu’s 3D desktop sometimes causes issues with Minecraft. You could try logging in with unity 2d instead and see if this improves your issues.Though im not really sure what you mean by "lags". Since not having the black screen of death issues, i presume you are using  minecraft version 1.3 .This should   work fine with the allocated ram,and shouldn't have the need to manually install the updated  Lightweight Java Game Library .

To answer your question

-Xmx sets the maximum memory and Xms sets the minimum memory

`java -Xmx2096M -Xms1048M -cp minecraft.jar net.minecraft.LauncherFrame`

changing 2096M and 1048M to the amounts you desire

Comment: Nobody mentions the most important thing: where on earth do you find the place to edit this?!

Answer (score 0):

edit your profile and add this command on JVM box
Command:

```
-Xmx2G -Xms2G
```

2 as GB memory replace any number for allocating more ram. For more detail [read more](http://www.howtominecraft.net/allocate-ram-minecraft/)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)